# excel array formula if result depends on row?

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, formula

It seems that the result of my array formula depends on the row. Please see the image attached. Cell `C2` looks up from the value of the cell above it (`s3`) from `$A$3:$A$11`, and tries to return values in `$B$3:$B$11` if matched. So are cells `D3`, `E4`, `F5`, etc. I expect the values should be the same. However, I got `Error in Value` for `C2`, `D3`, and `E4`, as well as `M12` and `N13`. I got `FALSE` in `F5`, `H7`, `I8`, `J9`, and `L11`. The only 2 cells that got valid results are `G6` and `K10` where the cells themselves are on the same row as where `s3` is found.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The formula in the screenshot has not been array-entered. If it had been, it would show "FALSE". The formula does not make sense, since it returns an array, not a single value. An array cannot be shown in a cell, so only the first value of the array will be returned.

Comment: I don't know how to post images in follow-up comments, I submitted [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489893) that describes my original question.