# How to arrange table data differently by using if, match, and index?

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, indexing, match

As shown in the attached image, I need to convert A2:D10 to the format of A12:E17. The 4 tables from F1 to AB12 are my experiments using if, match, and index. Same formula gets different results and it seems to be dependent on the row position of the tables. In [My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38468792/excel-array-formula-if-result-depends-on-row), I was trying to pinpoint the problem to the if function.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Thanks,
Lu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vI27.png)

Comment: If you could include the formula in text it means we don't have to retype it out for a break down.  Also as mentioned in the previous answer it doesn't appear you are entering it as an array formula (pressing **ctrl+shift+enter**).

Comment: I unmerged the merged cells. Here is the formula for cell G3: 
=INDEX($A$2:$D$10,MATCH($F3,IF($A$2:$A$10=G$2,$B$2:$B$10),0),MATCH(G$1,$A$2:$D$2,0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, as I said in your last question: The formula has not been array entered. Array formulas need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Without that, the first array in the IF statement does not get resolved and the Match does not return the correct result.

Make use of the Evaluate Formula tool and step through the formula.

The merged cells don't help with the cell referencing. Unmerge the cells and fill in all the labels in row 1, then use this slightly amended formula and confirm it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. Then copy across and down.

[image]

Comment: Personal preference but I would avoid the 2nd dimension in the **index,match** formula by directly referencing column C or D.  Might not be suitable for data sets with many columns though.

Comment: @gtwebb Yeah, but that would require different formulas for the four columns H to J. I wanted to show for the purpose of this exercise how it can be done with the existing setup.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-Enter works. Thank you! I didn't know that I need to press Ctrl-Shift-Enter on the formula for array to work. It now works!

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I get the English names of the functions right:

In D14 and following cells:

`=INDEX($C$1:$C$5;MATCH(1;MMULT(($B$3:$B$10=$A14)*($A$3:$A$10=B$13);1);0))`

The MATCH function tells which value (by number counted from the top) matches both conditions. The INDEX function returns this value from C1:C5.